# Can't augment my items in Diablo 3 on Xbox

Tags: diablo-iii

When trying augment none of my items show up in Kanai's cube, has anyone using Xbox been able to augment? I have tried everything that I can think of to get this to work.

Comment: Are you trying to augment Ancient items?

Comment: Yes Ancient items, when I go to the recipe nothing shows up no gear, gems or shards